# How to get and sort rows from MySQL Database by my formula?

Tags: java, mysql

I have table **post** with column **quantity of likes** and **date_time_of_creation**, table **comment** with foreign key on **post**. Topic "popular" should return posts which have to be sorted (DESC) by formula:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPHtz.png)

Comment: Can you please give more description?

Comment: I'm developing site on Java Spring boot, there is will be posts and possibilities to like it and send comments, Popular posts page should include posts which have to be sorted by my own formula(image in link) in descending order

Comment: What value should the **currentdate - dateTimeOfCreation** substraction result in? Days, hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: result should be in days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT p.*
      ,(0.33*quantity_of_likes + (SELECT count(*) FROM comment WHERE post_id = p.id))
       /EXP(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date_time_of_creation, NOW()) / 7) AS popularity
FROM post p
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

You can try above query, although you might need to change the unit argument in `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function as you didn't specify what valuetype should the substraction result in. You can use any of `MICROSECOND` (microseconds), `SECOND`, `MINUTE`, `HOUR`, `DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH`, `QUARTER`, or `YEAR`